# Robot framework: How to locate a lone input text field using Xpath

Tags: robotframework

I am a newbie but keen into test automation. Please don't hesitate to send and reply ANY hints you have.

So the problem is that I've faced a web page where there is input field but there is no ID for it in source. Input field has type=text AND that input field is THE ONLY on that page. I have not been able to locate that element with Robot Framework (+PyCharm) but I have a feeling that it should be possible some way in Xpath? Please help me.

Using `Input Text  xpath=//INPUT[@type='text']`  test -> gives this error:

> "InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state:
>   Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

I am afraid that the ancient framework used in system under test is the problem. It's called GWT-ext and in many cases there exists id for element but it's generated randomly every time so that cannot be used as locator of the element. That's why I need to use other ways, like field names, types etc.

Comment: please show what you've tried. If it's the only input on the page, it seems like it would be trivial to search for that specific tag.

Comment: I am not familiar with Xpath but you CSS language allows selection by element type. I recommend rephrasing your title as a question. For example, "How to locate a lone input text field using Xpath"

Comment: Bryan, I've been trying like follows: 1) Input Text  xpath=//INPUT[@type='text'] and also 2) Input Text  xpath=//div[contains(@class, "name_of_the_class)] but neither of those worked. The code looks like this: <input type="text" size="20" style="width: 175px;" and as I told you earlier, this is the only input field on that page. I cant stop wondering how xpath cant locate that element.

Comment: What does "neither of these worked" mean? Did you get an error? Please update your question with the actual code that you tried, along with any error messages or results. If you literally have a single input on a page, //input will find it. If it doesn't find it, there are other facts that we don't know about. For example, are you waiting for the page to render before you try to access the element? is the element in a frame?

Comment: Question and error message updated. When I added this "wait until page contains etc" the response message was the same: "InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

Comment: The message is quite clear. The Element *is* found, but is in a state that it can not be interacted with. This can be caused by several things. Can you please share the full code for your `INPUT` tag and any CSS that applies to it specifically or to the `INPUT` tag in general.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Here's the full code of this problematic INPUT:

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. What's weird also is that if I use Chrome add-on called Xpath helper and type "//INPUT" into Query field, the box at right says "Results (84)." So it kind of finds a lots of input fields although that that page there is only Input field (visible). Here's the full code of this problematic INPUT: <input type="text" size="20" id="ext-gen1123" name="ext-gen1123" class=" x-form-text x-form-field x-form-invalid " style="width: 175px;">